# Android - BitmapFactory.decodeStream() always returns null

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to download an image from the Internet to display in an Android app. I'm using an AsyncTask to avoid the NetworkOnMainThreadException, but BitmapFactory.decodeStream() is always returning null no matter what I do:

This is one of the methods I've tried:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {

    String url = args[0];
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL targetUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn  = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.reset();         // to allow reuse
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bm;
}
```

This also doesn't work:

```
try {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.reset();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return bm;
```

** Final method for adding image **

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap res) {
    img.setImageBitmap(res);    // img is an ImageView object for my Asynctask-extended class
}
```

**Logcat**

```
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at com.dannyc.facebooktestapp.FacebookFriendAdapter$ProfilePictureTask.onPostExecute(FacebookFriendAdapter.java:96)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at com.dannyc.facebooktestapp.FacebookFriendAdapter$ProfilePictureTask.onPostExecute(FacebookFriendAdapter.java:1)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5104)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 16:39:20.774: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've also tried BufferedInputStream, as well as other answers listed here, all to no avail. This is really driving me nuts. I'm using Android API level 8, if that helps.

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: what is the logcat output?

Comment: Yes. The answer is in your logcat. Post it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TzLuS332

Comment: @DannyChia Edit your post and add your `onPostExecute` method, please. Or at the very least line 96.

Comment: Calling `ImageView.setImageBitmap(null)` won't throw a NPE. So it seems that your `ImageView` is what's `null`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I was looking in the wrong place. everything seems to work now. Thanks for all the replies, everyone.